# Delphi: No VarIsBoolean( )-function?

Tags: delphi, boolean, variant

In variants.pas, there is several VarIsXXX( )-functions for type-checking a variant. There is no VarIsBoolean( ), though.

What's your preferred way of checking if a variant is of type boolean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
varIsType(v, varBoolean);
```

It is easy then to write your own VarIsBoolean function

```
function VarIsBoolean(const V: Variant): Boolean;
begin
   result := varIsType(v, varBoolean);
end;
```